# Infer type of an element in generic array, to access only type-specific fields

Tags: typescript

I need an array that can hold multiple interfaces. When I access an element of that array, I would like for its type to be inferred, such that only fields/methods available for that interface are accessible through it. Here's an example:

```
interface Person {
  brain: string;
}
    
interface Plant {
  root: string;
}

interface Being extends Partial<Person>, Partial<Plant> {}

const Bob: Person = { ... } 
const beings: Being[] = [];
beings.push(Bob);
```

This was my initial "solution." Since I wanted an array that can hold both `Person` and `Plant`, I created a new interface that extends both `Person` and `Plant` (i.e. `Being`), and made an array of it. But then `beings[0].brain` and `beings[0].root` are all theoretically possible (and also show up in my IDE autocomplete), which is not the behavior I want. I want only `brain` to be accessible for `Bob`.

I think what I'm looking for is in generics or conditional types, but I am desperately in need of enlightenment. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is impossible in TypeScript. If you want to be able to `push` an item of either type to the array, that means every time you do so, you are making a decision about which type goes in the new position *at runtime*. So to illustrate this

```
const bob: Person = { ... }
const tree: Plant = { ... }
const fred: Person = { ... } 
const beings: Being[] = [];
beings.push(bob);
beings.push(tree);
beings.push(fred);
```

Here, you want TypeScript to infer the type as `[Person, Plant, Person]`. Typescript isn't going to be able to do this.

Variables always get a type **at the point of declaration**, and that type doesn't ever change (unless it is a `let` variable and you use a type assertion, which you shouldn't do), so asking TypeScript to then *change* the type of the variable because a method was called on it is simply not how the compiler works.

There are a couple of reasons why it doesn't work like this that I can think of. This list is not exhaustive though, I'm sure if you asked a dev on the TS team they'd be able to give you more reasons.

### Types are analysed at **compile time**, not at **runtime**

```
const data = await functionThatReadsAnArrayFromAJsonFile()
const beings: YourMagicType[] = [];

data.forEach((being) => being.push(being))
```

Here, its not possible to know here at compile time how many times the forEach loop is going to run, or what the resulting type is going to be, as the JSON is parsed at **runtime**.

While its true that there might be a small number of situations where it might theoretically be possible to 100% know the type of every single variable passed into `push` and therefore statically infer the type of the array, in most sophisticated applications the instances of this being the case is going to be small enough for it not to be worth the engineering effort to implement as a feature.

### The TypeScript compiler doesn't have visibility on all the code that forms part of the program

In JavaScript (and therefore TypeScript) arrays are [passed by reference](https://www.educative.io/edpresso/pass-by-value-vs-pass-by-reference), which means if you pass it into a function, its possible for that function to mutate the original array.

If you consider the following code:

```
const data = await functionThatReadsAnArrayFromAJsonFile()
const beings: YourMagicType[] = [];
someFunction(beings)
```

someFunction **might** call `.push` on your `beings` array; so for what you are proposing to work, the TypeScript compiler would need to look *inside* that function to check whether any calls to `push` are made. This might be possible if `someFunction` is part of your code, but if it comes from a third party library, its *very* likely that the compiler has zero visibility on the implementation of that function at all (because most packages ship with javascript and type definitions separately).